# How to use android developer demos

Tags: android

Beginner question.  I'm working through the android developer training at http://developer.android.com/training/index.html and got to the second topic "Managing the Activity Lifecycle".  I have downloaded the ActivityLifecycle.zip demo but I don't know how to use it.  Can I load it as a project into Eclipse?  Do I have to add it to an existing project?  What do I do with it?

-Mike

Comment: Using Google would have been a better option for you but anyways check [here](http://rootfs.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/android-import-an-existed-android-project-into-eclipse/) or [here](http://android.programmerguru.com/how-to-import-android-project-in-eclipse/) for how to.

Comment: @LokeshMehra - I understand where the OP is coming from.  On the (android-developers dev group)[https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-developers] they suggest coming to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, you'll need to import it as a project using `File--> New Project --> Android --> Android Project from Existing Code` (on Eclipse Juno at least).

Comment: Its same with the other versions too. :)